# 2-d arrays PHP->JSON->jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a 2-dimensional array ( $array = array(array()) ) that I put through json_encode in php, and get something like...

```
[["209","2008-03-06","Technical Writing 1","009"],["210","2008-03-06","Technical Writing 2","005"]]
```

When I go to use `$.parseJSON()` on this string, it doesn't give me anything. Any thoughts?

EDIT
My jQuery looks like:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "stat_fetch.php",
    data: { },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $parsed = $.parseJSON(data);
    },
    async: false
});
```

Comment: What's your jQuery look like that fetches it? It's possible jQuery already parsed it for you.

Comment: Works fine for me .. what version of jQuery?

Comment: Whoops, left that part out :) It's edited into the post.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Why are you specifying the `dataType` as HTML if it is JSON? What is actually the response you get? What does `typeof data` and `console.dir(data)` give you?

Comment: I had run into some problems in the past with the JSON option, i will swap it and give it a try. EDIT: I ended up changing the datatype to JSON and it works great. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

Try indexing into the data you get back - for example

```
$.getJSON("/myprog/php",function (data) { alert(data[0][0]; });
```

will pop up an alert box with the value "209" from your array example above.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `$.parseJSON` doesn't work as I expect, I got problems in past with this. I think you can use simple javascript but the function `JSON.parse` is also buggy.

Read this about the `JSON.parse`: http://caniuse.com/json

I suggest you to use a library, like this:
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Try **json2.js** or **json_parse.js**, they work great and are crossbrowser.